# Twitter On The Fly login works half

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, authentication

I'm trying to implement Twitter Sharing in my app.

When the user hits a Twitter button, the following method is called:

```
TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc]init];
//here I configure the composer    
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore hasLoggedInUsers]) {
            [composer showFromViewController:self completion:nil];
        } else {
            [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
                if (session) {
                    [composer showFromViewController:self completion:nil];
                   } else {
                    //error handling
                }
            }];
        }
```

Now what I see happening is:
When there **are** logged in users, a share dialog is presented, as expected.
However, when there are **no** logged in users, a dialog is presented to allow the user to log in (expected). After successful login (I do have a session), no composer is presented (not expected).

Hitting the Twitter button again **does** present the composer.

Where do I go wrong in my logic.
Let me know if you need more information, logging, etc

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem was, I think, that

```
[composer showFromViewController:self completion:nil];
```

in the login block didn't work, because 'self' was dismissed.

To solve this, I now present the composer from the rootviewcontroller, as such

```
[composer showFromViewController:rootController completion:nil];
```

where rootcontroller is defined as

```
MyViewController *rootController = (MyViewController*)[[(myAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];
```